# distinct usage analysis

Tags: sql, database

I'm on an analysis task on an old query starting with a distinct on 200+ columns.
I'd like to know if the distinct is really necessary in this context. When I run the query with and without the distinct on the data of the last 2 weeks, it returns exactly the same number of rows. I don't want to just brutally run the two queries on the whole tables (way too much rows).
I already studied each of the 5 joins to study eventual cartesian products and 1-n, n-n, etc... relations between tables and that seems fine.

Do you have an idea as to how I should approach this study to be absolutely sure that the distinct is useless or not ?

Thanks !

Comment: Understand the relation between all the joined tables. If there is possibility of denormalised data, then distinct will prevent it. If every record will come out to be unique, you can remove the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

First determine the answers to these two questions:

1)  Does the DDL of the tables involved in the query allow for duplicate results to possibly be returned by my query if I take out the DISTINCT?

2)  Do I have a business requirement that my query only return distinct results?

If the answer to both of these questions is YES, then you need to keep the DISTINCT in your query.   Otherwise you don't.